# Same session between 2 apps Symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, session, config

Actually I have an app in symfony(2.3) but I need create another App in symfony (2.8) using the same session variables to login one time only.

I remember that in Symfony 1.4 I use the following conf to create this functionallity:

`storage:
    class: sfSessionStorage
    param:
      session_name: my_site
      session_cookie_domain:  .example.com`

Someone knows how can I do that in Symfony 2.3 and 2.8 ?

Answer (score 0):

[Framework Bundle Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session)

```
    session:
        handler_id:  ~
        name: my_site
        cookie_domain: .example.com
```

Comment: I tried to add this with the info below: `cookie_domain: 192.168.1.29:8888` but when I try to login does not work.